# Notation of original expression

Tags: notation

A problem contains a long expression that is required to prove. One can in the proof refer to that expression by numbers or stars (e.g: (1), *, **, etc). Is there a convention or a notation for referring to the original expression? For example OE, for Original Expression?

Possibly:

1. The required is equivalent to...
2. The original statement can be...
3. The original equality is...

Comment: This seems to be entirely a matter of taste.  You are trying to communicate an idea.  Use the language which you think most clearly does that.

Comment: I completely agree with @XanderHenderson: it's a matter of taste and style. From what you say, I'd suggest starting by saying "Our goal is to prove ..." and thereafter referring to "..." as "our goal".